# Jquery edit on click

Tags: jquery, show-hide, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to write a jquery function to make text editable on click.

I'm trying to use the data attr to find which `<p>` and input it should show and hide based on where the user clicked.

I've console logged the correct data attr so I can't see why it won't hide the `<p>` and then show the `<input>`

Can anyone see what is wrong with the function?

```
     <p class="editbox" data-gradeid="1">Original text</p>
<input data-gradeid="1">

<p class="editbox" data-gradeid="2">Original text</p>
<input data-gradeid="2"> 


$('p').click(function() {
        var input = $(this).attr("data-gradeid");
        console.log(input);
        // $('p').hide();
        $('p [data-gradeid='+ input + ']').hide();
        $('input [data-gradeid='+ input +']').show();
  });.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jheimpeld2l/3oexm0m5/

Comment: Remember [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/321253) the answer that works out to you. And feel free to ask new questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should not give a space between a selector and its own attribute.

Replace `'p [data-gradeid='` by `'p[data-gradeid='`.

When you use space you are saying that some element with `data-gradeid` is child of a `p` element, which is not the case.

---

**Edit:**

You can add an `enter` function to the jQuery library this way:

```
$.fn.enter = function(fx) {
    $(this).keypress(function(e) {
        e.keyCode === 13 && fx.apply(this);
    });
};
```

Then, looking for performance you can use `$.each()` and store each `$p` and `$input` elements to avoid further DOM processing:

```
$('p[data-gradeid]').each(function() {
    var $p = $(this);
    var gradeid = $p.data('gradeid');
    var $input = $('input[data-gradeid=' + gradeid + ']');

    $p.click(function() {
        $p.hide();
        $input.val($p.html()).show().focus();
    });

    $input.enter(function() {
        $input.hide();
        $p.html($input.val()).show();
    });
});
```

Here is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/se5zgjya/4/).

However, I suggest you using `blur` event as noted in the comments.

Comment: Thank you! That seemed to work. However, now the second function to save the value when entering doesnt. I've updated the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jheimpeld2l/se5zgjya/

Comment: Glad to see it worked :) You can also give a look at the [CSS Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: I've rewritten the functions to you [here](https://jsfiddle.net/se5zgjya/1/). Hope it helps.

Comment: do you see why the keypress function wont work in the second portion of this. I assumed it was the same issue but when I've updated with your suggestion it did not work. https://jsfiddle.net/jheimpeld2l/se5zgjya/

Comment: I think `keypress` is not the right event to handle your needs, look the link I posted in my previous comment.

Comment: thats awesome! Is there a way to make it save when you press enter as well? it looks like blur does not allow for that

Comment: I'm not at my computer now... but I think with `blur`  you can just use the `tab`-key. When I get home I'll look what can be done in an easy way to handle the `enter` key properly.

Comment: @jdheimpel. The code looks nice now... Hope it solves your needs :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the quotes around `$('p [data-gradeid="'+ input + '"]')` .

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('p').click(function() {
        var input = $(this).attr("data-gradeid");
        console.log(input);
        // $('p').hide();
        $('p[data-gradeid='+ input + ']').hide(1000);
        $('input [data-gradeid='+ input +']').show();
        
  })
    
    $("input").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
      $(this).prev("p").show(1000).text($(this).val());
      $($(this)).hide();
    }
        
  })
    
})
```

```html
 <p class="editbox" data-gradeid="1">Original text</p>
<input data-gradeid="1">

<p class="editbox" data-gradeid="2">Original text</p>
<input data-gradeid="2"> 

        
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```